# Can I search multiple table columns in SQLite using a wildcard?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table, contacts, that has a dozen columns or so. I want to identify each row in which at least one column contains a regular expression. I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like this:

```
select * from contacts where * like '%re%';
```

instead of this:

```
select * from contacts where last_name like '%re%' or first_name like '%re%' or ... ;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. Perhaps you could put a trigger on the table to update a single denormalized column?

Comment: Thanks. I think you're right. I was able to construct the query in Python easily enough.

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from contacts where concat(last_name, ' ', first_name) like '%re%'
```

Comment: Interesting. This isn't quite what I was looking for (I have 10+ columns for various fields), but this is good to know.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use like this to search in two column.**

```
String query = "select * from SomeTable
            where (column1 like ? and column2 like ?) and column3 like ?";
String[] params = {"%" + param1 + "%", "%" + param2 + "%", "%" + param3 + "%"};
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, params);
```